# Having 2 UIimageviews load the same pic

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uiimageview

I have 2 UIImageviews that I would like to share the same pic.png when the view controller loads. How do I link the UIImageviews to show the same pic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple

```
imageView1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"];
imageView2.image = imageView1.image;
```

Hope it helps you..

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way is as follows:

```
self.imageView1.image = myImage;
self.imageView2.image = myImage;
```

If you want them linked so they always show the same image, you’re best off putting making a method like this. I’ve put the `UIImageView`s in an array, to show how you could expand this technique to as many image views as you want:

```
- (void)showImage:(UIImage *)newImage
{
    for (UIImageView *imageView in imageViewsArray)
    {
        imageView.image = newImage;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set both UIImages to the same thing, or just give the second image the value of the first.

```
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"];
imageView2.image = imageView.image;
```